what exactly are the limitations of the require() function concerning my custom logic
I wrote some logic for a fundraising contract
    function fund() public payable {
        // myValue = myValue + 1;
        require(msg.value.getConversionRate(s_priceFeed) >= MINIMUM_USD, "ETH sent too small");
        s_funders.push(msg.sender);
        s_addressToAmountFunded[msg.sender] += msg.value;
        s_addressToContributionCount[msg.sender] += 1;
    }

now i then wrapped my fund function in a "receive()" function, so a user doesn't need to specifically call the function to fund, just a normal transfer to the contract would still fire off the "fund()" function.
receive() external payable{
  fund();
}

Now everything works just fine when I use a normal transfer to send eth to the contract, but the max gas stipend for "receive()" is 2300 but my "fund()" function costs around 113,000 gas. How come it still works as intended even though the receive function will now cost way more gas to execute?

The limit of 2300 only applies when you are sending ether via transfer or send.
Assuming that you are either sending ether via metamask, or scripts, which use call, the gas can be specified to be larger in this case. Hence, executing the function.
Try sending ether from another contract using send or transfer, to see it failing.

Thanks so much! the transaction reverted when I used transfer from another contract

I think you're confusing the amount of gas sent by the transfer function, which is 2300, with the receive function.
Take a look at this contract which interacts with your contract:
contract CallFundMe {
    function callFundMe(address payable fundMe) external payable {
        FundMe(fundMe).fund();
    }

    function callFundMeUsingTransfer(address payable fundMe) external payable {
        fundMe.transfer(msg.value);
    }
}

The function callFundMe calls the fundMe function in your contract directly. This is a regular contract interaction.
The function callFundMeUsingTransfer transfers ETH to your contract using the transfer function. Since the transfer function sends 2300 gas to the called contract and is insufficient for the target contract to execute its logic, this call reverts.
Your call doesn't revert because you're not using the transfer function. You're using either an EOA to call into the contract or the low level call function to send ETH.

thanks a lot, this helped
